# How to find nearest parent by tag_name with selenium

Tags: html, ruby, selenium, xpath

I'm working with "Table styled" web site by using `selenium-webdriver`.

There are a lot of nesting of tables and there are no `id` or `name` attributes of them.

So I decided to get header text in a table to find a place of data like this.

```
 driver = Selenimum::WebDriver.for :firefox
 element = driver.find_element(:xpath,
   "//font[@color='#FFFFFF' and text()='some probably unique text']")
```

from HTML like this.

```
<table><tbody>
...
<table><tbody><tr><td><font color="#FFFFFF">
  some probably unique text
</font></td></tr></table>
...
</tbody></table>
```

I want to get the inside `table` element from `font` element that I got in above code.
I know I can get with `element.find_element(:xpath, "../../../..")`, but it's a little disgusting.

I want to specify a tag name at least like this `element.find_element(:xpath, "../*/table")`.

Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use XPath axes `ancestor`.

```
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, ".//font[@color='#FFFFFF' and text()='some probably unique text']/ancestor::table")
```

<del>Or nested XPath: not for nested tables situation like yours</del>

```
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, ".//table[.//font[@color='#FFFFFF' and text()='some probably unique text']]")
```

Comment: The first is all right, but add a `(...)[1]` around it to fetch _nearest_ ancestor. The second just fetches all of them and doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @JensErat: Yeah, you are right, I thought tables were parallel, but they are nested.

Comment: Just realized it might be more reasonable to remove the parenthesis, in case multiple tables for multiple font elements are to be found; thus return the first table ancestor for each font element.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Capybara, nodes have a method `ancestor` that accepts a CSS selector (similar to JavaScript's `closest`).
For example:

```rb
table = find("font[color=FFFFFF]", text: "some probably unique text").ancestor("table")

within table do
  click_on "stuff"
end
```